# oninput does not fire on checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, jquery-events

The following code does not work on all input elements:

```
$(':input').on('input', function(){
  alert('boom shakalaka');
});
```

It has no effect on check-boxes even though they are input elements, and checking or unchecking changes its state.

I can add the `change` event too inside `on()` but then the same event will be fired twice on other input fields.

Is there any reliable input state-change event that is consistent for all form elements?

Comment: It will not fire twice if you will add `change` to `on` method

Comment: it does, i tested it. for eg. on selects... did you mean "input  change" or just "change" ? I cannot use change only bc the event handler has to run for text fields too

Comment: `.on('input change', function () {})`

Comment: Works only once for me: http://jsfiddle.net/84vK7/

Comment: @antyrat it triggers twice for the textbox

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7t3yw/

Comment: What browser are you testing in @thelolcat? In FF and Chrome it works just fine.

Answer (score 6):

There is no single event that would be authoritative, but you can bind to multiple events -

```
$(':input').on('change keyup input', function() {
    console.log('changed');
});
```

P.S. I wanted to give you a +1 for using 'boom shakalaka' in an example, but I digress.

Comment: does not work for text fields when you type something, you have to blur but the function has to run when the value changes

Comment: now it doesn't fire if you paste text with the mouse

Comment: note that this solution will result in two firings of the function whenever your user types something in a text input element (I think it's firing on both on input and keyup). If your function is idempotent this shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <!--Why not just use onclick ?-->
    <!--Ur-->
    <script>
    $('input#checkbox').on('click', function(){
      alert('boom shakalaka');
    });
    </script>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <!--Or-->
    <input type="checkbox" onclick="anyfunction();">
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if what you want but maybe a simple blur event?

```
$('input').on('blur',function(e){
      alert('event');
    });
```